# What is process._tickCallback Node.js error

Tags: node.js, error-handling

Me and my friend working on project in node.js. We had a error which we don't know what it is. Can you guys explain about it? Here's the error:

```
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
(node:10758) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwin
g inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().
 (rejection id: 2335)
```

P.S: My friend didn't allow me to post code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error happens when developers forget adding async error handling via `.catch()` or `try... catch`. Compare:

```js
(async function main() {
  try {
    await Promise.reject();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Rejection handled.');
  }
})();
```

```
Rejection handled.
```

```js
(async function main() {
  await Promise.reject();
})();
```

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ...
```